# Jboss-service.xml in Jboss is not understood by EAP 7

Tags: jboss-eap-7

1) We are migrating from Jboss 5 to EAP 7.
2) The same code deploys under jboss 5 but throws below error when deploying under EAP7

Can someone help with how we accomplish 
jboss-service.xml equivalent in EAP?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many changes in between JBoss 5 and the latest EAP.  You'll have to take a look at jboss-service.xml to see what it's trying to accomplish (this is generally just MBean configuration), there will be a new way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots changes between EAP 5 and EAP 7. JBoss-service .xml is no longer valid. You will have to configure using standalone or domain.xml.

If you need messaging or clustering support then you will have to choose Ha or full or Full-ha profile.